# Error : redefinition of default parameter

Tags: c++

I have two methods to implement named : Compute_correlation and cca. This is how I define them :

```
namespace dlib
{
     template <typename T>matrix<typename T::type,0,1> compute_correlations (
        const matrix_exp<T>& L,
        const matrix_exp<T>& R
       );

      template <typename T>matrix<T,0,1> cca (
        const matrix<T>& L,
        const matrix<T>& R,
        matrix<T>& Ltrans,
        matrix<T>& Rtrans,
        unsigned long num_correlations,
        unsigned long extra_rank = 5,
        unsigned long q = 2,
        double regularization = 0
       );

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {...}
    template <
        typename T
        >
    matrix<typename T::type,0,1> compute_correlations (
        const matrix_exp<T>& L,
        const matrix_exp<T>& R
    )
    {
        DLIB_ASSERT( L.size() > 0 && R.size() > 0 && L.nr() == R.nr(), 
            "\t matrix compute_correlations()"
            << "\n\t Invalid inputs were given to this function."
            << "\n\t L.size(): " << L.size()
            << "\n\t R.size(): " << R.size()
            << "\n\t L.nr():   " << L.nr()
            << "\n\t R.nr():   " << R.nr()
            );

        typedef typename T::type type;
        matrix<type> A, B, C;
        A = diag(trans(R)*L);
        B = sqrt(diag(trans(L)*L));
        C = sqrt(diag(trans(R)*R));
        A = pointwise_multiply(A , reciprocal(pointwise_multiply(B,C)));
        return A;
    }

    template <typename T>
    matrix<T,0,1> cca (
        const matrix<T>& L,
        const matrix<T>& R,
        matrix<T>& Ltrans,
        matrix<T>& Rtrans,
        unsigned long num_correlations,
        unsigned long extra_rank = 5,
        unsigned long q = 2,
        double regularization = 0
    )
    {
        DLIB_ASSERT( num_correlations > 0 && L.size() > 0 && R.size() > 0 && L.nr() == R.nr() &&
            regularization >= 0, 
            "\t matrix cca()"
            << "\n\t Invalid inputs were given to this function."
            << "\n\t num_correlations: " << num_correlations 
            << "\n\t regularization:   " << regularization 
            << "\n\t L.size(): " << L.size()
            << "\n\t R.size(): " << R.size()
            << "\n\t L.nr():   " << L.nr()
            << "\n\t R.nr():   " << R.nr()
            );

        using std::min;
        const unsigned long n = min(num_correlations, (unsigned long)min(R.nr(),min(L.nc(), R.nc())));
        return impl_cca(L,R,Ltrans, Rtrans, num_correlations, extra_rank, q, n, regularization); 
    }
```

I am trying to implement them from main, but the following error is shown:
redefinition of default parameter. Please help me

Comment: the error occurs because you are trying to redefine the default parameters, just dont do it and the error will be gone

Comment: if I don't define it, it will give an error

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the assignment for the default parameters from the argument list of the function definition.

Comment: Thank you! The error is gone, but this error is shown: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: This happens only when you have used some things for which compiler is not able to locate the definition.
Please tell what are the variables for which you are getting linking errors.

And yes the this error is independent of your previous error.

Also refer the link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361308/fatal-error-lnk1120-4-unresolved-externals) for more help on linking errors.

Comment: please help me where to find the varibales I have to tell about

Comment: You must me getting those names in error messages

Comment: 1>  LINK : C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Implementation-CCA\Debug\Implementation-CCA.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Implementation-CCA\Debug\Implementation-CCA.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: This is the output of running

Comment: You might have picked the wrong type of the project at the start in your visual studio.
what project did you choose?
Are you developing a independent application ( a smaller application) kindly create a new project in visual studio as console application --> empty project and then try to write your code and compile.

Comment: I tried this, new project, empty but the same error still occured

Comment: My apologies for my previous comment.
kindly place your main function (i.e. int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {...}) outside the namespace in your existing project.
i.e. place this main outside namespace "dlib".


This should work.

Comment: in this way, the matrix becomes not defined.. :(

Comment: For that you can have forward declaration for your class or  move the class declaration in .h header file and include that header.

Comment: You might consider writting new question for your new problem when it gets solved.

Comment: I have a header file and it is included, but the matrix still not defined.. I will write a new question.

Comment: As it is a template class so every type you are using must be forward declared. You might check it by reducing your code only in type of the matrix class and forward declare and then forward declare all the types or simple solution to this problem is moving all the function definition (yes i said definition) to the header file so that all type variants of this class are ready.

Comment: Please this is the new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942947/error-fatal-error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-externals

Comment: Can you check your facebook inbox please @Kaushalendra

Comment: Hey @H.Y did not get any, you might have found the different guy.

Answer (score 4):

You should set default parameters only in the declaration, not in the definition (implemenation).
In your case, remove the `= 0` parts where their appear in the function implementation.

[The compiler is complaining about my default parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210450/the-compiler-is-complaining-about-my-default-parameters)

Comment: ... and `= 5` and `= 2` as well ;-)

Comment: Thank you! The error is gone, but this error is shown: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Do you have any idea about it? @SpamBot

Comment: Our coding standard was to comment out the default parameters in the definition. E.g. unsigned long extra_rank /* = 5 */. When the declaration is in a separate .h file, it helps the reader know what the default is.

Comment: @BryanT And then the *actual* default value is changed in the declaration, and the comment is disastrously unhelpful.

Comment: @Biffen - that's true, but it also applies to any comments in the method's parameter descriptions. In retrospect - keeping the decl and any comments in agreement is enough. (The standards weren't mine.)